# How to make `environ["wsgi.input"].read()` fast?

Tags: python, gunicorn

I am using raw `gunicorn` without a framework. I am sending POST request to a server. I have code as follows on the server side:

```
def get_args(environ):
    # ...
    request_body = environ["wsgi.input"].read().decode('utf-8')
    # ...
```

If all request takes 0.97 secs then 0.93 secs is processing of `environ["wsgi.input"].read()`.

What should I fix to make its processing faster?

Comment: Send your data faster? How large is the file you are POSTing anyway?

Comment: @MartijnPieters It is about 200kb

Comment: The `.read()` cannot be made faster; you are waiting for the network to complete sending all the data.